# Differential Geometry - vector fields Lie bracket

Tags: differential-geometry, summation, lie-groups

[image]

Can anyone tell me why (in the last line) $i$ changes to $j$ in the first component of the sum?

Comment: Have you cheked [the wiki article on the summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)? Those are called dummy indices

Comment: Yes, I know this convention. Still I have no idea why it looks like this. For example, second component looks the same as in the previous line

Answer (score 1):

Repeated indices are interchangeable as long as you don't have more than two of the same letter in a single term. E.g.
$$a_ib^i = a_jb^j = a_kb^k$$

In your case
$$X^i\frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} = X^j\frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$$